# SNMP bandwidth and response time

Tags: snmp, bandwidth

I've been trying to learn about SNMP Protocol (as a beginner)

When studying network performance, we look at three main points:
- Bandwidth
- Response Time
- Devices Availability

But which of these info can we get using SNMP?
I know of Response time, but not sure of the others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can get all those data via SNMP. By using below OID, you can retrieve the data

```
> OID                           Object Nanme
> 1.3.6.1.2.1.34.9.1.1.1.2      tn3270eRtCollCtlType(Respose Time/Not sure!)
> 1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.8           ifOperStatus (Interface Status)
> 1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.5           ifSpeed (Bandwidth)
```

If you have OID, [HERE](http://cric.grenoble.cnrs.fr/Administrateurs/Outils/MIBS/) You can check details of that OID. Google the OID for Device status/Availability.(I couldn't get, but definitely there will! )